# jquery calculated list items not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some Jquery which will calculate the width of the UL to then divide it by the number of list items, giving them a value so the menu fits full width.

The problem is i have menu items which dont show fully as the code is calculating the list item rather than the string length in the A.

Cartridges/Cylinders doesnt show correctly and Garden & DIY is wrapped to the next line.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="new-menu-lower">
  <ul class="menuul">
   <li class="menuli">
       <a href="/test.aspx">Barbecues</a>
   </li>
      <li class="menuli">
       <a href="/test.aspx">Stoves</a>
   </li>
      <li class="menuli">
       <a href="/test.aspx">Lanterns</a>
   </li>
      <li class="menuli">
       <a href="/test.aspx">Cartridges/Cylinders</a>
   </li>
      <li class="menuli">
       <a href="/test.aspx">Coolers</a>
   </li>
      <li class="menuli">
       <a href="/test.aspx">Boats</a>
   </li>
      <li class="menuli">
       <a href="/test.aspx">Airbeds</a>
   </li>
      <li class="menuli">
       <a href="/test.aspx">Garden & DIY</a>
   </li>
      <li class="menuli">
       <a href="/test.aspx">Toilets</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
//set the menu li sizes once everything has loaded.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#new-menu-lower ul li').css('width', ($('div#new-menu-lower ul').width() / $('div#new-menu-lower ul li').length));
    $(function() {
        var menuWidth = $('div#new-menu-lower ul').width();
        var listItems = $('div#new-menu-lower > ul > li').length;
        alert('The UL is calculated at: ' + menuWidth + 'px');
        var itemWidth = Math.floor(menuWidth * (1 / listItems)) - 20;
        $('div#new-menu-lower ul li').css('width', itemWidth);
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
div.container
{
    clear: both;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    width:960px;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:700px;
}

div#new-menu-lower {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    border-top: 0 solid lightgrey;
    margin: 0 8px 10px;
}

#new-menu-lower ul {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    display: block;
    height: 27px;
}

#new-menu-lower ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 0 solid lightgrey !important;
    border-radius: 7px 0 0 7px;
}

#new-menu-lower ul li {
    background-image: url("http://i45.tinypic.com/16if95z.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-right: 0 solid lightgrey !important;
    float: left;
    height: 27px;
    padding-left: ;
    padding-right:;
    text-align: center;
    width: 168px;
    margin-left:1px;
}
```

**DEMO:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/rM9MW/45/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a simpler solution. Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HHHDW/1/) which i've created for you.

You don't need to use jquery, but only css.

Comment: I've didn't inspect your javascript code, but in this cases you have to try using just html and css :) it's more accurate like this

Answer (score 1):

You substract 20 pixels from element width but your margin and padding of `LI` element is zero. If you erase this 20px  you should consider substracting 1px from every element to include border width.

In other words, change this:

```
var itemWidth = Math.floor(menuWidth * (1 / listItems)) - 20;
```

to this:

```
var itemWidth = Math.floor(menuWidth * (1 / listItems)) - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var itemWidth = Math.floor(menuWidth * (1 / listItems)) - 20;
```

to

```
var itemWidth = Math.floor(menuWidth * (1 / listItems)) - 1;
```

And

```
   </li>
      <li class="menuli">
       <a href="/test.aspx">Garden & DIY</a>
   </li>
```

To

```
   </li>
      <li class="menuli">
       <a href="/test.aspx">Garden&nbsp;&&nbsp;DIY</a>
   </li>
```

[Update demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rM9MW/48/)

Comment: Wow, great repost. You should be proud. And one more thing: using $nbsp; is retarded.